# Redirect_to 'category_products_path' after destroy not working (:category_id not given)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to redirect_to category_products after @product.destroy, which I cannot get the :category_id.  I don't know how to redirect without the :category_id back to product#index.  Below is my products_controller.rb, rake routes, and error message - anyone know a quick fix?

products_controller.rb (destroy)

```
def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to category_products_path(@category), notice: 'Pro$
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
 end
```

rake routes:

```
category_products GET    /categories/:category_id/products(.:format)                                              products#index
```

error:  "Couldn't find Category without an ID"

Comment: Try `redirect_to category_products_path(params[:category_id])`

Comment: @JagdeepSingh - There is no `params[:category_id]` which is why Belvin is getting the `find` error. Based on Belvin's prior posts, I figure they are using shallowly-nested routes.

Comment: _"trying to redirect_to category_products after @product.destroy"_ - From here, i assume, destroy is working fine. The issue is with redirect in the response of destroy action. This _"I don't know how to redirect without the :category_id back to product#index"_ also says the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your params, you'll see there is no `params[:category_id]` because you're using shallow nesting.

Try something more like:

```
def destroy
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @category = @product.category
  @product.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to category_products_path(@category), notice: 'Pro$
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

This, naturally, assumes that `Product belongs_to :category`.

(I'm ignoring that trailing `$` because there seems to be something off about your editor or copy-and-paste.)

Comment: That did it, thank you.  And yes Product belongs_to :category.  I was not sure how to reference @product.category - that all makes sense now thanks.

Comment: Sure thing. You'll get the hang of it. BTW, as always, feel free to upvote/accept for future searchers.

Comment: _"If you look at your params, you'll see there is no params[:category_id] because you're using shallow nesting."_ - Where do you see the params and the mention of shallow nesting?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh - Great questions! Welp. First, it's clear that `params[:category_id]` doesn't exist because `@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])` throws `"Couldn't find Category without an ID"`. So, one doesn't really need to see the `params` to know that `category_id` isn't there. Second, `category_products_path` indicates nesting and the absence of `params[:category_id]` suggests shallow nesting. But, I've also seen Belvin's prior questions in which we've discussed shallow nesting - so I sort of cheated.